# JavaFx Binding NumberExpression "Transactions"

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm not quite sure how to word this, so forgive my question's title.

I'm having an issue where the value of a NumberExpression is changing before I am able to update all of the properties that go into its evaluation. The following code creates a NumberExpression `aMinusB`, and triggers some output whenever that value is less than zero. I have to update both `a` and `b`, but as soon as I update `a` (as you'd expect) it updates `aMinusB` and reevaluates and says "Less than Zero!!!" then I update `b` and it's no longer less than zero.

I'd like to be able to update both `a` and `b` at the same time so `aMinusB` is never less than zero.

The following code demonstrates the issue.

```
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanExpression;
import javafx.beans.binding.NumberExpression;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

public class Binding
{
    private static SimpleIntegerProperty a;
    private static SimpleIntegerProperty b;


    public Binding()
    {
        a = new SimpleIntegerProperty(10);
        b = new SimpleIntegerProperty(9);
        final NumberExpression aMinusB = a.subtract(b);
        BooleanExpression lessThanZero = aMinusB.lessThan(0);
        lessThanZero.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)
            {
                if (newValue)
                {
                    //This is triggered each time aMinusB is less than zero
                    System.out.format("Less than Zero!!! A=%s B=%s A-B=%s",
                             a.get(),
                             b.get(),
                             aMinusB.getValue());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void update(int aUpdate, int bUpdate)
    {
        //I'd like to wrap these two calls in some sort of transaction      
        //so they both get updated before aMinusB is evaluated again
        a.set(aUpdate);
        b.set(bUpdate);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.update(4, 3); //4 minus 3 is greater than 0
    }
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
Less than Zero!!! A=4 B=9 A-B=-5
```

The values change from

```
     INITIALLY: A=10  B=9  A-B=1
a.set(aUpdate): A=4   B=9  A-B=-5
b.set(bUpdate): A=4   B:3  A-B=1
```

I'd like to be able to update both `a`'s value and `b`'s value at the same time without the `aMinusB` expression getting evaluated until they are both updated.

Note, swapping the setters (i.e. b.set() before a.set()) isn't an option because the same problem exists for a greaterThan scenario as well.

*Recap:* is there any way for me to update the value of `a` and `b` at the same time before `aMinusB` is evaluated?

Comment: Take a look at the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework for JavaFX and see if it supports the functionality you want (I'm not sure if it does or not).